# Parse Array Query, Retrieving Array Values

Tags: android, arrays, parse-platform

Quick question on retrieving a column set as an Array through parse. So I have an existing class with a column set as an array that is filled in with values. I am attempting to retrieve this array and extract each value from the array in a for loop. My code is below:

```
String sOne;
List<String> sCArray2 = new ArrayList<String>();

public void done(List<ParseObject> cList, ParseException e) {
                    if (e == null) {
                        if (cList.size() > 0) {
                            //Results found!
                            for (ParseObject Params : cList) {
                                //Retrieve Parse values for user input
                                wString = Params.getString("w");
                                dateString = "Date";

                                sCArray2 = Params.getList("sCArray");

                                for (int i = 0; i<sCArray2.size(); i++) {
                                    sOne = sCArray2.get(i);
                                }
```

Where "sCArray" is the name of the parse column.

I keep getting the following error:

"java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to java.lang.String"

The only thing I could think of is that the function .getList("sCArray") is passing the existing array into the sCArray2 (Making an array of arrays). I don't think that's the case though as I attempted to extract the array (in position 0) out of sCArray2 by making a new array and doing:

```
sCArray3 = sCArray2.get(0);
```

This told me that the type here is String.

So how can I extract the information from the parse array here? Any help?

Comment: When you use naming like cList, sCArray2, sCarray3 etc, it makes it much harder for anyone reading your code (including yourself when you haven't worked on it for a few months) to understand what is going on. Try to use names that clearly describes the data that they store. What data should be contained in sCArray?

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I do have more descriptive names in my actual code, just abbreviated them here. sCArray is a parse column set to array that contains strings

Answer (score 0):

I have answered this question myself - The problem was that I was sending an array into the existing array so I was left with : [ [] ]. It wasn't detecting a string in there as it was reading the array within the array.

I sent this into the array by using:

```
submitObject.put("parseArrayColumn",Arrays.asList(cArray));
```

What I had to do was extract the values out of cArray and then send them into the array column in parse by doing:

```
submitObject.put("parseArrayColumn",Arrays.asList("cArrayValueOne","cArrayValueTwo"));
```